# Given an array of digits 0-9 and an integer n, find all the integers which can be formed from the input array and are less than n

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here is the problem:

> You are given an array of digits 0-9 and an integer *n*. The array may contain duplicates of any given digit. Find all the integers which can be formed by contatenating digits from the input array and are less than *n*. Digits from the input array can be repeated in an element in the output.
>
> For example, given as inputs [2, 5, 8] and n = 223, then the following should be the output:
>
> [2, 5, 8, 22, 25, 28, 52, 55, 58, 82, 85, 88, 222]

Obviously any integer with fewer digits than *n* would be accepted and any with more denied. But how to most efficiently find those with the same number of digits?A solution I know of would be to have nested for loops, one for each digit in the input integer, and form every possible combination of digits from the input array and check it against *n*. This seems clunky though and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: You could iteratively generate base-3 numbers and then convert their digits from [0,1,2] to [2,5,8].

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion.

Write a function that outputs all answers with the same number of digits as `n`. Call this function `doit(n)`. Then, a pseudo-code for it:

1. Find the most significant digit of `n`, call it `d`
2. For all digits `d1` smaller than `d`, output all numbers starting with `d1`
3. Remove the digit `d` from `n`; call the result `n1`
4. Call `doit(n1)`; to each number in the resulting list, prepend the digit `d`

Comment: From a runtime complexity standpoint, I am interested in doit(n) though. Wouldn't that be the limiting factor? I can't see any way that it wouldn't consist of the tons of nested for loops from my original question (have nested for loops, one for each digit in the input integer, and form every possible combination of digits from the input array).

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question on that. Or search the existing questions; I am sure some good question and answer on that already exists. "Output all combinations", or something like that.

Comment: @programming_challenge, I think you're missing the point of *recursion* in this answer. It is exactly that which will avoid you having to write those *"tons of nested loops"*. Step 4 is avoiding all that.

Comment: There are two parts to his solution: 1) doit(), which I'm thinking would need the nested loops, and 2) the recurisve part that utilizes doit. I don't see any way around nested loops to implement doit() and that seems like it would be the limiting factor from a run time complexity standpoint.