# Given an array of digits 0-9 and an integer n, find all the integers which can be formed from the input array with number of digits = n

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Note this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141615/given-an-array-of-digits-0-9-and-an-integer-n-find-all-the-integers-which-can-b), but rather a subproblem of it.

Here is the problem:

> You are given an array of digits 0-9 and an integer n. The array may contain duplicates of any given digit. Find all the integers which can be formed by contatenating digits from the input array and have n digits. Digits from the input array can be repeated in an element in the output.
>
> For example, given as inputs [2, 5] and n = 3, then the following should be the output:
>
> [222, 225, 252, 255, 522, 525, 552, 555]

Note that this is what Python's [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) calculates. Their algorithm is listed at that link - I'm not able to determine its runtime complexity though but I'm guessing it's optimal. What is the runtime complexity of that solution?

Comment: There's no algorithm here, so runtime of what?Please show your own thoughts and attempts at the solution http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: See edit, I linked out to Python's documentation

Comment: From that page, it's at least `O(n!)`, plus the returned elements will always be `n! / (n-r)!` long, so just generating that list will require a factorial runtime

Comment: Please follow `How-to-ask` guidelines of stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Before asking for solution show us what you have done. This is not a free service.

Comment: Updated question to point at documentation for product instead of permutation. Since only 10 different elements at most can make up the input (the 10 digits), wouldn't the runtime complexity be `O(10^n)`, where n is the number of digits in each output element?

Comment: The complexity is at least O(n * m^n) where `m` is the number of digits in the array, and `n` is the number digits in each number.  For example, given [2,5] and n=3, that's `3*2^3 = 24`, which is the number of digits in the output (eight numbers, three digits per number).

Comment: @user3386109 Why not `O(m^n)` ? (if we omit leading zero's subtleties)

Comment: @MBo For example, the array is [3] and n=600billion. `m^n` is just 1, but it's going to take a long time, and a lot of memory to generate the answer.

Comment: @user3386109 `m` is 10 in the worst case for the constraints laid out in the problem

Comment: @user3386109 OK, now I see that you account for costs of result formation.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string> result;

// storing the concatenation of digits as a string as it is to operate on, we can convert the concatenated string to int at the end.

FormDigits(vector<int> input, int index, int n, string ndigits) {

 // if the ndigits size has reached n
 // Check whether that is already present in the result as we have repeating digits
 if(ndigits.size() == n && result.find(ndigits) != result.end()) { 
     result.push(ndigits);
 } 

  // if ndigits size hasnt yet reached run a loop and add next digit 
 else {
    for(int i=index; i<input.size(); i++) {
        FormDigits(input,i,n,digit+to_string(arr[i]));
    }
 }
}
```

The above function should be called from main as

```
FormDigits(InputArray, 0, n, "");
```

The result vector is the final output.

Comment: So this would have runtime complexity of O(10^(ndigits))?

Comment: yeah thats the complexity @programming_challenge